CSS initial-letter property in Safari doesn't inherit font-family
In Chrome / Blink based browsers, the initial-letter property inherits the font-family applied to body to render dropcaps.
The CSS:
@supports (initial-letter: 2) or (-webkit-initial-letter: 2) { 
    p.para::first-letter { 
        -webkit-initial-letter: 2;
        initial-letter: 2;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin-right: 0.3em;
        margin-top: 0.1em;
    }
}

Example with the font-family OpenDyslexic on body in Chrome:

But the same in Safari mobile and desktop (Webkit) renders as:

I tried adding explicit font inheritance:
@supports (initial-letter: 2) or (-webkit-initial-letter: 2) { 
    p.para::first-letter { 
        -webkit-initial-letter: 2;
        initial-letter: 2;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin-right: 0.3em;
        margin-top: 0.1em;
        font-family: inherit !important;
        font-weight: inherit !important;
        font-style: inherit !important;
    }
}

Which does not resolve the issue. I also tried font-family: "OpenDyslexic" !important; directly as well.
I found an unanswered SO question about a similar issue from 7 years ago: initial-letter doesn't show the correct font
I think it's related to this open bug on Bugzilla, with non-local fonts:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195002

Confirmed on caniuse.com that the Safari implementation of initial-letter is incomplete. If you need a solution which works in Safari today you will need to use float rather than initial-letter.

@BrettDonald thanks for confirming. Unfortunately will need to write JS calculations to determine line height as well, since there's n number of font families users can apply to their works which need to be styled.

Perhaps the better choice is to use initial-letter anyway and encourage users of your application to avoid Safari.

Got options. Display wrong font on safari, not display dropcap on safari (probably possible), make a polyfill with JS, edit HTML markup and do it the old way. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/initial-letter/
